# Simple 3D drawing VB.net

Tags: vb.net, 3d, drawing

im creating one simple application which will generate some NC code for a machine. It is very simple project, only some valve where i add Diameter and lenght.

I would like to make a preview of this valve. But have small experience with a 3D graphics in .NET .

Do exist some easy way how to make this preview in 3D?

Thanks very much for any advice.

Marek

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/53632033-6bfe-433f-8ac6-090126327766/3d-graphics-in-vbnet?forum=Vsexpressvb

Comment: Hello, thanks very much. I will check it.